# Posthoc connect FFMPEG to opencv-python binary for Google Cloud Dataflow job

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ffmpeg, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to run some video processing jobs on linux based compute engines on Google Cloud DataFlow. Cloud DataFlow requires you to build a setup.py file, or supply dependencies in a requirements.txt.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python

My video process requires opencv in python with FFMPEG support. I would like to avoid building opencv from source, as this takes nearly 35 minutes for each worker to git clone/make/make install.

There is a linux python binary .whl that works great. But its specifically compiled without FFMPEG.

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

"IMPORTANT NOTE

MacOS and Linux wheels have currently some limitations:

video related functionality is not supported (not compiled with FFmpeg)"

Is it possible to post-hoc connect FFMPEG to the binary? That is download FFMPEG and its libraries separately and still read video? I know this is contrived, but are are there any options here besides building opencv from source for every new worker?

Comment: Hey, I'm on the Dataflow team and am trying to figure out whether you want anything in particular from Dataflow here, or is this a question about how to use opencv with ffmpeg without compiling opencv from source in general? Are you able to accomplish that in a non-Dataflow context?

Comment: Just a thought: perhaps can you compile opencv with ffmpeg on your machine (I don't know how to do this but I'm sure it's possible), and then use https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python#local-or-non-pypi-dependencies ?

Comment: @jkff the challenge is that dataflow doesn't allow docker containers, so my understanding was that every dependency must be built on each machine. Are you suggesting that I could compile opencv and ffmpeg on my compute instance and just label the path their compiled directories when calling dataflow? That is not my reading on the docs at all. What I was doing was using custom commands in setup.py to git clone, make, and make install, such that each machine separately built the library. This added atleast 35 minutes to the beginning of each worker spinup.

Comment: Just noticed that you asked a similar question last week https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958387/python-dependencies-in-cloud-dataflow-requirements-txt-works-locally-but-not-o - have you tried the solution suggested in the answer, with building a .whl file locally (I mean building a version of opencv with ffmpeg yourself on your machine, whatever that takes) and staging it with your pipeline via --extra_packages?

Comment: (we are also working on providing the ability to use custom containers, but it's not available yet)

Comment: Ah, no, I tried the python .whl provided online, but not build my own. It worked great, just no FFMPEG> Let me look into what it takes to create ones own whl.